# Why my image is just visible in debug mode

Tags: javascript, react-native

When I run in debug mode , my app shows the images .But when i go to release the image just desapear.

I fetch an url image from an api. This API return me that :

[{"IdDesconto":"3","IdStatus":"16","imagemProduto":"http://app.vaideoculos.com.br/promocao/Cupom_VDO_02.png","tituloDesconto":"Pegue seu desconto de 50% nas armacoes da VDo da nossa marca , aproveite !","codigoDesconto":"UE77UE","descricaoDesconto":"Este Oculos \u00e9 da marca VDO , marca da loja propria!","descricaoValidade":"Este cupom \u00e9 valido em todas as lojas.","dataInicial":"2019-05-01 10:00:00","dataFinal":"2019-06-25 10:00:00","dataCriada":"2019-05-01 09:09:09"},{"IdDesconto":"1","IdStatus":"16","imagemProduto":"http://app.vaideoculos.com.br/promocao/cupom1.png","tituloDesconto":"Pegue seu desconto em oculos Ray - Voucher de 20% de desconto","codigoDesconto":"RD5BUE","descricaoDesconto":"Este oculos \u00e9 um rayban solar tamanho 52 justin para jovens e etc... ","descricaoValidade":"Este cupom \u00e9 valido somente na loja do butanta zona sul e para o oculos justin de tamanho 52.","dataInicial":"2019-05-01 10:00:00","dataFinal":"2019-07-10 10:00:00","dataCriada":"2019-05-01 09:09:09"}]

```
for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(this.state.descontos).length; i++) {
  render.push(

<View style={{flex:1,backgroundColor:'#fff',borderRadius:15,marginVertical:50,justifyContent:'space-between',alignItems:'center'}}>
<View style = {{margin:20,height:'50%',width:'90%'}}>

  <Image
      style={{resizeMode:'contain',flex:1,height:300,width:300,alignSelf:"center"}}
      source={{uri:this.state.descontos[i].imagemProduto}}


  />
</View>
<View style={{alignItems:'center',width:'90%'}}>
  <Text style={{fontSize:17,color:"#000",textAlign:'center',marginBottom:10}}>{this.state.descontos[i].tituloDesconto}</Text>
  <Text style={{fontSize:12,textAlign:'center'}}>{this.state.descontos[i].descricaoDesconto}</Text>
</View>
<TouchableHighlight
      style={[styles.buttonContainer, styles.loginButton]}
      onPress={() => 
        {
          if(this.state.loged != null && this.state.loged != "")
            Alert.alert("Ver código",this.state.descontos[i].codigoDesconto)
          else
          {
            Alert.alert(
              'Para adquirir o desconto você precisa estar logado',
              'Deseja logar agora?',
              [

                {
                  text: 'Não',
                  style: 'cancel',
                },
                {text: 'Sim', onPress: () => this.props.navigation.navigate('Login')},
              ],
              {cancelable: false},
            );



          }
        }



        }
    >

      <Text style={{color:'#fff'}}>Ver Código</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>


</View>
  )}
```

Comment: You didn't specify whether this happens on iOS or Android. But I believe this is related to https issue. Are you fetching items via http-only endpoint? If so, then either switch to https or search for instructions for allowing http requests.

Comment: It was just happening with android.Idk why

Comment: It was related to the https , I changed to https and it works ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the image url was with http protocol and it seens that need to be https